# MySQLi CREATE Table query not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE comments 
(
ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PosterName VARCHAR(32),
Title VARCHAR(32),
Content VARCHAR(500)
)";
$con->query($sql);
```

No errors, connection to database is successful. Does anyone know why it doesnt work?

Comment: The `$con->query()` method would've returned false if  there was an error, and you would then need to output `$con->error` to see the error message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should have seen that error with that statement:

> Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key:

---

`auto_increment` column *must* have an `UNIQUE`index on them, or more generally being the `PRIMARY KEY`:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE comments 
(
ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
PosterName VARCHAR(32),
Title VARCHAR(32),
Content VARCHAR(500)
)";
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess that was the problem. Weird how no errors were appearing for me :o Marking as best answer